# Running database script Hosting to IIS on pre built web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to run this sample web application in visual studio 2012

ASP.NET MVC 4 Sample (Magazine website)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-4-Sample-37924d68#content

But I am new to MVC and Microsoft Visual studio and connecting to or creating databases in general.

I don't understand how to complete two of the steps he mentions to get the application running.

Step 2: Run a database script, the script can be find at C#\1.DatabaseScripts\3.NewsDbScript.sql

Step 3: Host CIK.News.Web to IIS host

When I try to run the database script I get a connect to server screen and don't know what to do from there.

Can I get a more detailed explanation on how to complete these two steps and what it is accomplishing?

Comment: ***ISS*** ?!?? You're deploying to the International Space Station??? ***WOW !!!!***

Comment: Internal Sarcastic Services more likely.